# Order of operations not properly working on Python. Anyone know what's happening?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on Python 2.7. I created a simple program that takes the radius (r = 6) of a sphere and calculates its volume. I used parentheses to try to group higher precedences together. When I used this program:

```
> import math as m
> sphere = (4/3)*(m.pi)*(6**3)
> print(sphere)
```

I obtained an incorrect value of 678.58

When I used this program:

> `import math as m`
> `sphere = (4)*(m.pi)*(6**3)/3`
> `print(sphere)`

Regardless of how the parentheses were grouped, as long as I put the denominator at the end of the equation, I obtained the correct value 904.77792.

Comment: Try it in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that result of

```
x = 4/3
print(x) # this will print 1
```

Because 4 is of an integer type and you divide it by another integer. Therefore Python(2.7) returns 1 instead of 1.3333333. If you want to get a decimal value you can do

```
import math as m
sphere = (4.0/3)*(m.pi)*(6**3)
print(sphere)
```

In the second case when number `m.pi` is floating, this is why you get a correct result as you dividing floating number by integer.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, this is a matter of integer vs. float division.

To make division work like in Python 3 (i.e. always float division, unless you specifically use `//`), just start your program with:

```py
from __future__ import division
```

...which will change the behavior of `/` to what you expect.

**But is there any specific reason why you're using Python 2.7?** It's been deprecated and it is not supported anymore. Aim to use Python 3 for new projects.

Comment: you're right. i'll make that switch. thank you for the help.

Comment: @mza You can mark an answer as accepted if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

In Pyhton 2.7, a division between two `int` produces a `int` result. You can solve this by typecasting one of the arguments in the divisions to be float using  one of the following options:

- Add a dot in one argument:

```py
x = (4./3)  # 1.33333
```

- Explicit typecast of one argument:

```py
x = (float(4)/3)  # 1.33333
```

By the way, do you really need to use Python 2.x? If you are developing something new, I recomend you to migrate to Python 3.x, because [Python 2 has been deprecated](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) in 2020.